# Java spring userRegister creates two database entries instead of one

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

As above this creates two database entries in user table.
The process should be following:

1. a new user enters their email and password
   -> saved in login table
2. user confirm Email address
   -> entry in user table with username (email) and first&second name should be null at first.

For second the code would be like that (working)

```
User user = new User("username", null, null)
```

```java
public RegistrationConfirmResponse registerNewUser(User user, String password) {
        loginRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).get().setUsername(null);
        userRepository.save(user);
        passwordRepository.save(new Password(user.getUserId(), password));
        return new RegistrationConfirmResponse("done", user.getUsername());
    }
```

is returning

`{"answer":"done","username":null}`

in Database creates this 2 entries

| ID | enabled | fistname | locked | secondname | username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | NULL | 0 | NULL | test@example.com |
| 2 | 0 | NULL | 0 | NULL | NULL |

The entry with ID 1 is correct but number 2 must not be created.

RegistrationConfirmResponse

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationConfirmResponse {
    private String answer;
    private String username;
}
```

Method calling registerNewUser

```java
@Transactional
    public RegistrationConfirmResponse confirmToken(String token){
        var confirmationToken = confirmationTokenService.getToken(token);
        var confirmedAt = confirmationToken.getConfirmedAt();
        /* Uncommented due to testing usage
        if(confirmedAt != null && Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), confirmedAt).toSeconds() < 10) {
                System.out.println(Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), confirmedAt).toString());
                throw new IllegalStateException("email already confirmed confirmed at " + confirmedAt);
        }*/
        LocalDateTime expiredAt = confirmationToken.getExpiredAt();
        if(expiredAt.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())){
            throw new IllegalStateException("token expired");
        }
        confirmationToken.setConfirmedAt(LocalDateTime.now());

        var user = new User(confirmationToken.getLogin().getUsername(), null, null);
        confirmationToken.getLogin().setUsername(null);
        return userService.registerNewUser(user, confirmationToken.getLogin().getPassword());
    }
```

Comment: You save twice.

Comment: I save one time in userRepository and one time in passwordRepository
That are different tables

Comment: Thats not how JPA works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:

I removed the Login table
and write directly in user table

now everything is working as it should be

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).